# How to POST custom json to telegram api

Tags: json, post, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Is it possible to send custom JSON (not the Telegram API method) to the Telegram API  in order to later parse the body of this POST request inside the bot

JSON example:

```
{
"id":"123456",
"something":"some value"
}
```

Method maybe?

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/????????
```

Parameters maybe?

```
https://t.me/botname?something=???
```

If possible, how to catch this json ?

I tried to post request to this urls:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot_token/
https://t.me/botname
https://t.me/botname?start
https://t.me/botname?custom
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chatid = 0000000000
token = "0000000000:xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
text = 'test-test-test'
url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage"
requests.post(url, data={
        "chat_id": chatid,
        "text": text })
```